# Can't to make a word as a code in comments

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting, markdown

I want to make --> This\ <-- as a code, so I add ` before and after:

`This\`

But It don't change to a code style! you can see and try it under this post in first comment!

Comment: `This\` is a code style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In comments, you can use *double* backticks to allow for a backslash before the closing backticks:

```
``This\``
```

This renders the word in backticks with the fixed-with font style, see the comment below this answer for a demonstration.

Comment: Demo: ``This\``

Comment: ``This\`` is a code style

Comment: It has no style! (Its color don't changed!)

Comment: @TheGoodUser: That's because here *on Meta* the code style has no change in background colour. That is *just a style choice*.

Comment: OK, Right. I tested it in SO. Thanks

Comment: @TheGoodUser: `This is a code style` without backslashes and just single backticks; note that it is rendered using a *fixed with font*, but no background colour change. On Stack Overflow itself a background colour *is* used for the code style in comments.